# Entity Framework BuildContainsExpression Causes Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025

Tags: entity-framework, internal

I'm trying to get the following LINQ query to work against the database (3.5 SP1):

```
var labelIds = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
var customersAggregatedTransactionsByType =
    (from transactions in context.TransactionSet
    from customers in context.CustomerSet
        .Where(LinqTools.BuildContainsExpression<Billing.Customer, int>(u => u.LabelId, labelIds))
    from accounts in context.AccountSet
    where customers == accounts.Customer
        && accounts.Id == transactions.Account.Id
        && transactions.DateTime >= fromDate && transactions.DateTime < toDate
    group transactions.Amount
    by new
    {
        UserAccountId = transactions.Account.Id,
        TransactionTypeId = transactions.TransactionTypeId,
        BaseAssetId = accounts.BaseAssetId
    } into customerTransactions
    select customerTransactions).ToList();
```

Once I add `Where(LinqTools.BuildContainsExpression<Billing.Customer, int>(u => u.LabelId, labelIds))` I get the following exception:

**System.InvalidOperationException: Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025.**

If I remove `Where(LinqTools.BuildContainsExpression<Billing.Customer, int>(u => u.LabelId, labelIds))` all's good.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks, Nir.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
        var labelIds = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
        var exp = LinqTools.BuildContainsExpression<Billing.Customer, int>(u => u.LabelId, labelIds);
        var customersAggregatedTransactionsByType =
             (from transactions in context.TransactionSet
              from customers in context.CustomerSet.Where(exp)
              from accounts in context.AccountSet
              where customers == accounts.Customer
                 && accounts.Id == transactions.Account.Id
                 && transactions.DateTime >= fromDate && transactions.DateTime < toDate
              group transactions.Amount
              by new
              {
                  UserAccountId = transactions.Account.Id,
                  TransactionTypeId = transactions.TransactionTypeId,
                  BaseAssetId = accounts.BaseAssetId
              } into customerTransactions
              select customerTransactions).ToList();
```

You want the *result* in the query, not the call to `LinqTools.BuildContainsExpression` itself.

Comment: Oh, you genius! I opened a bounty on a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11990158/7850) just an hour ago, and only later found your answer.  Please go and get yourself a bounty over there.

Comment: It sounds obvious, but you are correct, the expression must be built outside of the query itself.