# Func declared as a variable used in .Where() crashes my application

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, extension-methods, func

I have something like this:

```
Func<Thread, bool> tmpFunc = thread => true;
threads = Threads.Where(tmpFunc).(...)
```

Now, when I do `Threads.Where(thread => true).(...)` everything is okay, but using variable in `.Where()` crashes my application. Why? Am I doing something wrong?

Okay, so here is the code that reproduces the error:

```
var threads = context.Categories
    .Where(c => c.Name == variable)
   .Select(c => new
   {
       threads = c.Threads
           .Where(tmpFunc)
           .OrderByDescending(t => t.DateCreated)
           .Skip(threadsToSkip)
           .Take(threadsPerPage)
           .Select(t => new
           {
               t,
               CategoryName = t.Category.Name,
               AuthorName = t.Author.UserName, 
               t.Posts.Count,
               LastPost = t.Posts
                   .OrderByDescending(post => post.DateCreated)
                   .Select(p => new{p.Author.UserName, p.DateCreated})
                   .FirstOrDefault()
            }),
            c.Threads.Count
    }).Single();
```

And the error it gives me is **internal .net framework data provider error 1025**

Comment: can you post an example of something that causes the crash?

Comment: Crashes your application how? Which exception do you get? Do you ever modify the `tmpFunc` variable? Can you post a short code sample that can be compiled and reproduces the problem?

Comment: Edited my post. I realize that this is much code, i am trying to shorten it abit now, but can't since such errors like this one with Func<> are ocurring.

Comment: Format that code as well please .. nobody wants to scroll so far to the right just to read your code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an `Expression` instead of the `Func` directly:

```
Expression<Func<Thread, bool>> tmpFuncExpr = thread => true;
```

While `Linq2Objects` will be happy with the `Func`, `Linq2Sql` will not.

Comment: Just did this right now but i got this error: http://i.imgur.com/Fuvmb.jpg And have no idea what to do now...

Comment: @ojek - I am not an expert with EF, but can you try `c.Threads.AsQueryable().Where(tmpFunc)` instead of `c.Threads.Where(tmpFunc)`

Comment: Oh. Okay, that works. Thanks. But... What is the difference between AsQueryable and AsEnumerable?

Comment: @Ojek - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet

Answer (score 3):

My assumption is that there is no translatiin of a custom func to sql and the func is used in the projection. Although I would expect a "no sql translation for ... exists" exception.

To fix this, you could try declare your func as

```
Expression<Func<Thread, bool>> tmpFunc = thread => true;
threads = Threads.Where(tmpFunc).(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're using the Entity Framework, any predicate passed to the EF's IQueryable has to be the `Expression<Func<>>.`

Check this answer [stackoverflow.com/questions/11990158...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990158/internal-net-framework-data-provider-error-1025)