# Find String matches any in List of Strings

Tags: c#, string, list, entity-framework, contains

How to find string with a exact match in the list of string.

```
var inv_attr_string_id = inv_attr
                             .Where(x => ItemStringVal.Contains(x.STRING_VAL))
                             .Select(x => x.ID).ToList();
```

`ItemStringVal` Contains list of Strings like `"0030", "1433", "2019"` etc ... Now I am trying to match it with the database in such a way that if it match exactly and all the three strings then it returns me the list of IDs matched ... else it should return null.

I tried

```
List<int> inv_attr_string_id = new List<int>();
foreach (var StrItem in ItemStringVal)
{
    inv_attr_string_id.AddRange
                        (
                            inv_attr.Where(x => x.STRING_VAL.Contains(StrItem))
                                    .Select(x => x.ID).ToList()
                        );
}
```

I have tried `.Any` as well but I got an error saying ["Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22048912/3796048)

I was thinking if I could be able to write it the way it creates a query of AND condition such as it should match **(Exactly)** all the input `strings`.

One Liner could be: **Select IDs if all the string matches. Else return null**

Comment: Show the database data you expect to be matched by this. You can't ask a database to give you `WHERE a = '1' AND a = '2'` - that's always false

Comment: Did you mean like https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/03/25/tip-8-how-to-write-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities/ ?

Comment: That last part with 3 && conditions will never work. The thought itself is wrong.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava, what if your database contains 100 records and your list also contains 100 so you want to get all 100 records from db if **All** matches with your list *or* Anyone matches with you list

Comment: @er-sho It should return **ALL**

Comment: @MohitShrivastava, try this=> `bool result = inv_attr.All(x => ItemStringVal.Any(y => y == x.STRING_VAL));` you will get true if all your list items matches in your db records otherwise false. so you can implement your code based on above result

Comment: Try this this will return all those records from db which are matches with your list => `var result = inv_attr.Where(x => ItemStringVal.Exists(y => y == x.STRING_VAL)).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();` and let me know

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem - You have a list of strings which is your Input Data. You also have a List of patterns that may match with Data. You want to find the pairs of [Data, Pattern]?

Upfront this can be solved in O(N^2).

Psuedo Logic be like:

1. Foreach item in DataCollection
2. Foreach pattern in PatternCollection
3. if(Regex.IsMatch(item, pattern)) Then collect the item & pattern in some place

Hope this gives some starting point for you to solve the problem.

Comment: Nope I believe its not the pattern I am talking about. I think is exact values to be matched.

Comment: :( A Pattern is not always open ended. "Hello World" string is also a Pattern. Which will only have Exact Match or No MATCH.

Answer (score 0):

You can try linq to get all those records from db which are exist int your list

```
var result = inv_attr.AsEnumerable().Where(x => ItemStringVal.Exists(y => y == x.STRING_VAL)).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Got an error message:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Exists(System.Predicate`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Try to use `AsEnumerable()` before `.Where` like `inv_arrt.AsEnumerable().Where...`

Comment: This returns the exact result as `inv_attr
                             .Where(x => ItemStringVal.Contains(x.STRING_VAL))
                             .Select(x => x.ID).ToList();`

Comment: Yes you stated that in your post => **Select IDs if all the string matches. Else return null**